# Combining class extension with recursion

Tags: c#

I have some code that walks a supplied path and gathers file information.  In order to have the system continue to be able to tunnel further into the file tree, I added a DirectoryInfo field, then a BranchLevel counter to keep the thing from running off into oblivion on a network file system.

So, that all works fine.  I collect the data, then attempt to serialize it into JSON.  Unfortunately, serialization of the DirectoryInfo object, which I no longer need at that point, is causing problems.  I thought about creating a base class, then extending the class with the DirectoryInfo and BranchLevel fields, then converting to the base class before serialization.  This seemed sensible until I attempted it, got all confused, and came here for help.

Here's the class definition:

```
public class TreeInfo {
    public TreeInfo(int CurrentLevel) {
        BranchLevel = CurrentLevel;
        Children = new List<TreeInfo>();
        Fileset = new List<FileInfo>();
    }

    public System.IO.DirectoryInfo DirInfo { get; set; }     // <-- Don't want to serialize
    public int BranchLevel;     // <-- Don't need to serialize, but it's not the end of the world

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TreeInfo> Children { get; set; }
    public List<FileInfo> Fileset { get; set; }
}
```

I thought to create a class without the two identified members, then extend it to add those members.  But since the base class has a list of Children that is typed as itself, is extension even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a [ScriptIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx) attribute (or similar for your serialisation library) to the fields that you do not want serialised?

Comment: Glad it helped :). Would it be possible for you to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the post, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I tried before and the system said I had to wait one minute before I could accept.  I tried to wait, but... Squirrel!